# Using on_<widget>_<signal> where widget it own class

Tags: c++, qt4

Is there a way to use the naming convention described in the title to connect a signal from your own class.

E.g:

```
class MyTree : public QTreeWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

private slots:
    void on_this_itemClicked(QTreeWidgetItem* item, int column);
};
```

i understand i could use connect like this...

```
connect(this, SIGNAL(itemClicked(QTreeWidgetItem*, int)), this, SLOT(myItemClicked(QTreeWidgetItem*, int)));
```

...but i was just curious as to if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am quite sure Qt auto connection use the `objectName` (`QObject::setObjectName()`), so there is no chance it can resolve `this`.